# Phalcon model command worng path

Tags: php, model, path, entity, phalcon

I'm trying to generate an entity class with the `phalcon model pedido_item` command and the generator, for some unknown reason (to me) seems to be pointing to my project's parent directory (Applications) instead of its own.

Here's the error I get.

> PHP Warning: 
>   file_put_contents(/home/nmobregon/Applications/app/models/PedidoItem.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/nmobregon/phalcon-devtools/scripts/Phalcon/Builder/Model.php on
>   line 519
>                                                                                          Error: Unable to write to
>   /home/nmobregon/Applications/app/models/PedidoItem.php

Of course I haven't touched the generator code so it seems really strange that somehow is now pointing to a worng path.

Any ideas? Please tell me if I should add more info.

Thanks

Comment: did u created ur project by generator?

Comment: Yes :( I found a workaround forcing the output folder 

phalcon model pedido_item --output= /home/nmobregon/Applications/project/app/models/

But I don't like it, I don't want to be forced to include that parameter